# How to stretch value for the lengths of column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a df

```
df = 

date        foo   bar
2019-01-01  foo1  bar1
2019-02-01  foo2  bar2
2019-03-01  foo3  bar3
```

and a variable df_if = '123'

I need to make an additional column df_id with the value of df_if

```
# My desirable output is:

date        foo   bar   df_id
2019-01-01  foo1  bar1  123
2019-02-01  foo2  bar2  123
2019-03-01  foo3  bar3  123
```

I tried to do like this

```
df['df_id'] = df_id * len(df)
```

But it multiplies also the variable itself

```
# The result is:

date        foo   bar   df_id
2019-01-01  foo1  bar1  123123123
2019-02-01  foo2  bar2  123123123
2019-03-01  foo3  bar3  123123123
```

In other script the same technique works properly, I can't get why it multiplies the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is string, so if multiple by scalar it repeat values:

```
print ('a' * 3)
aaa

print (df_id * 3)
123123123
```

Maybe you want convert values to one element list:

```
print (['a'] * 3)
['a', 'a', 'a']

print ([df_id] * 3)
['123', '123', '123']

df['df_id'] = [df_id] * len(df)
```

But simpliest is:

```
df['df_id'] = df_id
```

Or:

```
df = df.assign(df_id = df_id)
```